# Read and push a table again to sql:Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I am reading a table from my sql server with Pandas such as

```
df= pd.read_sql('table1', engine)
```

where engine is my pyodbc connection 
 and then again I am pushing it to sql server

```
df.to_sql('table2', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

which gives me an error

```
ValueError: duplicate name in index/columns: cannot insert level_0, already exists
```

and when I try to drop the column, it gave me some another error, which is anyways not an efficient way. I tried this as well, which also didn't work

```
 df= df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Every help will be important

Comment: try `index=Flase` while wrting `to_sql` because index values should be unique.

Comment: It def works, so silly of me, If you want to post an answer, I will accept it as the answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

Set `index=Flase` while  writing `to_sql` because index values should be unique.